# Как вывести на экран только те слова, где встречается два слова подряд?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# ввожу с клавиатуры строку: Привет пока 12 когда 11 что где 
string = input()

# преобразование строки в список
arr = string.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
```

нужно пройтись в цикле по элементам списка, и вывести на экран только те элементы, где встречаются два слова (типа str) подряд:

[image: должно получиться]

Comment: Мне кажется, следующим шагом нужно: там где длина элемента списка <=2:
преобразовать элемент списка в int.
Или по-другому как-то.

Comment: нет, конечно же. Во-первых, общеизвестно, что есть числа длиннее двух символов, так же общеизвестно, что есть слова из двух и даже из одной буквы. Вам поможет функция string.isdigit()

Comment: А если три слова подряд встретятся, что нужно выводить? Или такого заведомо не будет?

Comment: Где же ваша попытка решить задачу?

Comment: string = input()
arr = string.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)

Comment: CrazyElf только два слова подряд. Тогда нужно выводить. Если три, то не нужно.

Comment: Эникейщик, спасибо за подсказку насчет функции isdigit. Буду копать в этом направлении. Пробую сделать хотя-бы костыли, и трехзначные числа не рассматривать. Мне главное, чтоб stepik.org пропустил решение. И тогда откроются варианты решений других людей, чтоб можно было посмотреть как они сделали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

your_str = 'привет пока 12 когда 11 что где'

print(*[i.strip() for i in re.split('\d+', your_str) if len(i.strip().split()) >= 2], sep='\n')

>>> привет пока
    что где
```

**Как это работает. Пойдем с середины.**

1. С помощью метода *split* библиотеки *re* и соответствующего регулярного выражения разделим строку по тем местам, где стоят числа, получим список.
2. Далее с помощью генератора пройдемся по этому списку. Т.к. у нас могут быть лишние пробелы, избавимся от них.
3. Пропишем условие, что длина каждого элемента из списка, опять же разбитого уже по пробелу, должна быть больше или равна 2 (так и не понял из условия, должно быть четко 2 или не менее 2 слов, если что можно подправить).
4. Выводим результат без скобок с переносом на каждую строку, как в примере.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Код работает. И всё подробно разъяснили.

Comment: По условию имелось ввиду: "если слово из нашего списка состоит из двух или менее символов". Но можно было не решать по количеству символов в слове, а попробовать другим способом. Это кому как больше нравится. Ваше решение хорошее.